# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'createNewEvent'

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, integration-testing

I am writing a Unit Test for my input box in Angular 11.

Here is my spec.ts code:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import 'jasmine';
import { ExpectedConditions } from 'protractor';
import { MicroplateComponent } from './microplate.component';

describe('MicroplateComponent', () => {
  let component: MicroplateComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MicroplateComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MicroplateComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MicroplateComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('Evaluation of input box', () => {
    it('Should return true for "1, 2, 3"', () => {
      const input = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
      const event = createNewEvent('input'); // I get error at this line

      input.value = '1, 2, 3';
      input.dispatchEvent(event);

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.columns?.valid).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

I get the following error, but I don't know where I am wrong.

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'createNewEvent'.`

I have used such an approach from angular website.

Comment: missing import? `createNewEvent` is not defined anywhere

Comment: @MikeS., Because I don't know where 'createNewEvent' is located.

Comment: I think it's component.createNewEvent or something... (assuming it's a function in your component)

Comment: Did the most upvoted answer solve your problem? I am coming across similar issue going through the Angular tutorial. The top answer did get rid of the error, but the event does not seem to be dispatched, because the "expect" part failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to invoke an input event that's how you do it:

```
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```